# How to bypass 'headless' reCaptcha V2?

Tags: python, authentication, web-scraping, bots, recaptcha

I'm creating a bot using requests, BeautifulSoup, and possibly Twill. The bot will scrape a large number of forums and gather data from them. However, the current forum I am working on (https://wearedevs.net/) uses reCaptcha V2 on its login page, so the bot cannot log in. I discovered this when after trying to log in through code, and instead of returning a valid response and reloading the page, I would continuously get a 404 error. I thought it was an error with my code, but even when trying Twill it still didn't log in.

I need to be able to log in through the site so I can access features that guest users wouldn't be able to access.

I knew the site had reCaptcha, so I looked into a reCaptcha bypass, the issue is it's not the visual reCaptcha, it's the "headless" version. As shown below:

[image]

Bottom right corner of the page:

[image]

In other words, it's the reCaptcha that doesn't give you a captcha prompt but instead analyzes your behavior on the site and determines if you're a bot or not.

I suspected that the 404 was because the reCaptcha determining that the requests were bots. So the second thing I attempted was sending a direct POST request from the code to the sites API, which is here:

https://wearedevs.net/api/v1/account/login

Along with the required JSON data, which is in this format:

{"g-recaptcha-response":"recaptcha-response-here", "username": "example_username", "password": "example_password", "token2fa": ""}

I didn't have a valid reCaptcha response to send to the server, so I tried excluding that from the JSON data but, while the request was successful, the server sent back an error saying that the login failed because a reCaptcha response was not present.

So then I tried using BeautifulSoup to send a request to the login page, grab the reCaptcha response, then include that in the JSON data to be sent, but I was unable to grab the reCaptcha response using BeautifulSoup.

I have tried Selenium, but I'm currently working in an environment in which a browser is not present, so Selenium won't work and therefore is not an option.

If anyone has any ways to bypass, or validate, the headless reCaptcha V2, please share and I would be grateful. Thanks!

Comment: Bump, I need help in this

Comment: Why whenever I post I get no help on any of my posts